# Cannot run py as command

Tags: python, python-3.x

On Windows I can run `py test.py` having Python 3 installed.
But on Ubuntu, `py` is not recognized as command, but `python3` is.

Is there anyway I can make `py` the same command as python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always add `alias py='python3'` to your .bashrc file.

Comment: And could you pls tell me where is that file? I kinda new on ubuntu

Comment: Go to your home directory and type `ls -a`.

Comment: Okey, and once inside that file, where should I type that? On the ``more alias`` section?

Comment: Anywhere is fine, but best to put it on a newline at the end so you can keep track of the changes you make to it. If there is an alias section, then put it there.

Comment: Well, I added it as you said, but ``py: command not found``

Comment: You need to source the .bashrc file. Type `source ~/.bashrc` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Oooooh it worked ^^ tyvm But... what is the source for?

Comment: When you open a Terminal or Konsole, the system reads the .bashrc file. Sourcing the file just makes the system read it again without having to log out and log back in again.

Comment: Ah, okey, thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

To add Up , If the script wants to call the interpreter

1. Make sure the first line of your file has #!/usr/bin/env python.
2. Make it executable - chmod +x .py.
3. And run it as ./.py